# Rename several image from each item

Tags: python-3.x, image, scrapy, rename

I want to rename images downloaded with my spider, all works well except he take only one image per item
how can i do to rename images for example like this:

- "object_title_1.jpg"
- "object_title_2.jpg"
- "object_title_3.jpg"

Here is my code:

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    #Name download version
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        image_guid = request.meta['Titre']
        log.msg(image_guid, level=log.DEBUG)
        return 'full/%s.jpg' % (image_guid)

    #Name thumbnail version

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        yield Request(item['image_urls'][0], meta=item)
```

This code works except I have only the first image by object

```
item.py
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item

class OscarsItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls=scrapy.Field()
    images=scrapy.Field()
    Titre = scrapy.Field()
    Ville = scrapy.Field()
    Annonceur = scrapy.Field()
    Prix = scrapy.Field()
    Statut = scrapy.Field()
    Description = scrapy.Field()
    Tel = scrapy.Field()
    index =scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: Can you show how your item looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting on the first image from the list in the get_media_requests method. If you want to download all images, you can rewrite to something like this:

```
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for image_url in item['image_urls']:
        yield Request(image_url, meta=item)
```

If you want to track the sequence number to use it when renaming, you can pass it in the meta:

```
def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        image_guid = request.meta['Titre']
        index = request.meta['index']
        log.msg(image_guid, level=log.DEBUG)
        return 'full/%s_%s.jpg' % (image_guid, index)


def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for index, image_url in enumerate(item['image_urls'], 1):
        meta = item
        meta['index'] = index
        yield Request(image_url, meta=meta)
```

Comment: hi added this to my spider to grab index: 'index':response.xpath("//span[@id='imgrightspan']/text()").get(),       i can see the index value in json file , but nothing download , can you tell me what i do wrong please

Comment: Better open another question and give the link to the website from where you try to get this